# Custom switch appears huge using custom drawables

Tags: android, xml, toggle, toggleswitch

I'm making a custom `switch` using 3 drawable files. Two icons, `On` and `Off`, represented by 89x89 images, and a custom `Track` drawable resource (colored black) which is 171x93. When I set my custom drawables to the switch, it stretches to the size of the images. How can I down-scale these images to fit exactly and no bigger than the text itself?

This is my `switch` xml:

```
<Switch
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/switchAnimation"
        android:thumb="@drawable/my_switch"
        android:switchMinWidth="55dp"
        android:track="@drawable/toggle_track"
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn=""
        android:textColor="#FFF"/>
```

The drawable of the switch my_switch.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_on" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_off" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

The drawable of the track:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_track" />
    <item                               android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_track" />
</selector>
```

I have tested this on two emulator devices, Galaxy nexus API 21, and Nexus 4 API 19. Another question, I've also notices that upon a click on the switch in API 19 devices there is no smooth transition animation like in API 21 (instead the icons just appear and disappear), is this normal?!
[image: nexus 4 API 19 with custom black track]

![nenxus 4 API 19 with out custom track][2]

[image: galaxy nenxus API 21 with black track]

EDIT
I made the resources a lot smaller, 25x25, now it appears the right size, but it looks a little bit pixelated. Is there any way to down-scale the quality icons to a smaller size?

Answer (score 2):

Simply add stroke with zero opacity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_enabled="true">
        <shape android:shape="oval" android:visible="true">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
            <size android:width="20dp" android:height="20dp" />
            <stroke android:width="7dp" android:color="#00000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_enabled="false">
        <shape android:shape="oval" android:visible="true">
            <solid android:color="#ccc" />
            <size android:width="20dp" android:height="20dp" />
            <stroke android:width="7dp" android:color="#00000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V315E.png)